# Char array value will print as empty unless value is printed when assigned - C

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf

I am working with two functions in my c program and am having trouble getting them to cooperate.  My first function iterates through a csv file and uses strtok() to separate tokens based on the ',' delimiter.  Each token is saved into a character array of size 3 and if a particular token does not match the goal token, the next line of input is read, tokenized, and the character array is overwritten with the new input tokens.

Here is the global variable used:

```
char * stateCityZip[3];
```

Here is the code for the first function:

```
int zipToCity(char * zip)
{
char line[1024];
char * tok = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
FILE * file = fopen("cityzip.csv", "r");
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
{
    //State
    tok = strtok(line, ",");
    stateCityZip[0] = tok;
    //City
    tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    stateCityZip[1] = tok;
    //Zip
    tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    stateCityZip[2] = tok;

    if (strcmp(stateCityZip[2], newZip) == 0) {
        //printf("Found %s, %s\n", stateCityZip[0], stateCityZip[1]);
        strlen(stateCityZip[1]));
        return 1;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

My second function is simply trying to print the values of stateCityZip.  When I print these values, however, they appear as blank.  The only way to fix this I'v found is to uncomment the

```
//printf("Found %s, %s\n", stateCityZip[0], stateCityZip[1]);
```

line.

Here is the code for my second function:

```
int main() {
    printf("City: [%s]", stateCityZip[1]);
    printf("State: [%s]", stateCityZip[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
City: []
State: []
```

Comment: `strtok` returns `char*` so when you do `tok = strtok(line, ",");` you are leaking the memory which is allocated to `tok` using `malloc` so don't allocate memory to `tok`.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Even after changing the definition of tok to: "char * tok", it behaves the same way.

Comment: Please refer to Daniel Pryden answer. My first comment just tells you the possible memory leak and doesn't solve your problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok` returns pointers to substrings of its input. So all your `tok` values are pointers to parts of `line`, which has automatic storage duration, and so the pointers in `stateCityZip` all become invalid once `zipToCity` returns.

(Actually, if there is more than one line in the file, the `tok` pointers all become invalid as soon as you advance to the next line, as they now point into arbitrary substrings of the new line in the buffer.)

Instead, you should use `strdup` to allocate a copy of the token as a new string, and save the pointer returned from `strdup` into `stateCityZip`.

An important note: the strings allocated by `strdup` need to freed by `free`. If `stateCityZip` is global then you can get away with not freeing them (the last memory will be freed when your process exits). But if `zipToCity` ever gets called again, it will overwrite the pointers in `stateCityZip` and leak the corresponding strings. So it would probably be safest to first `free()` any strings in `stateCityZip` (if they're NULL, then that's fine, as `free(NULL)` is a no-op) before assigning new values.

On the subject of memory allocation: your example code has a `malloc` call for `tok` which is completely superfluous, and which is guaranteed to leak, since you overwrite the pointer returned from `malloc` without ever `free`ing it.

And, on the subject of good coding practice: `fopen` can fail. You need to check that the returned `FILE *` is not NULL. (If it is NULL, `errno` will tell you why.) And you also need to `fclose` the `FILE *`, which you don't appear to be doing either.

More generally: none of this code appears to be doing any error checking at all. Every time you call *any* standard library function (or any function at all, for that matter!) you need to think about how that function could fail to do what it's supposed to do, how you would be able to tell (usually failure behavior is well documented, so make sure to read the docs), and what you want your program to do if it fails. What should happen if the file doesn't exist or can't be read? If it contains a line that isn't comma-delimited, or doesn't contain the expected number of fields? What should happen if you run out of memory halfway through processing the file, or if `strdup` isn't able to copy the string because you're out of heap memory? If you don't think about these problems, or forget to deal with them, you might get away with it in the "happy case" where everything works, but sooner or later it will come back and bite you -- often at the worst possible time.

Comment: You should also point out memory leak with `tok` pointer as a complete answer.